# How to transform a given Lagrangian to a Nambu-Gorkov basis?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, quantum-chromodynamics, research-level, elementary-particles

With reference to the Nambu (or famously, Nambu-Gorkov) transformation in [this paper](https://sci-hub.st/https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.117.648), could someone explain the reason behind using the 3rd Pauli matrix in the Lagrangian after equation (2.3) (would essentially like to understand how to do a Nambu-Gorkov transformation for any arbitrary (Lorentz-invariant)Lagrangian)?

P.S - another reference that's usually given along with the above is [here](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_007_03_0505.pdf), though I'm primarily following [1](https://sci-hub.st/https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.117.648).

Answer (score 3):

It's because
$$
\psi^\dagger \psi= \frac 12 (\psi^\dagger \psi-\psi \psi^\dagger)+const.\\
= \frac 12 (\psi^\dagger,\psi)\left[\matrix{1&0\cr0&-1}\right] \left[\matrix{\psi\cr \psi^\dagger}\right]+const\\
=\frac 12 \Psi^\dagger \tau_3 \Psi+const.
$$

Comment: I understood the above calculation & see why 3rd Pauli matrix is used (in the 2nd term) of the transformed Lagrangian. Now, expanding (only) the first term in eq. (2.1) for i=1 to 2, we see that the time-derivative term (for i=2 spinor) in the transformed Lagrangian (the one with Nambu-Gorkov bispinors) comes out differently from the corresponding term in eq. (2.1). In other words, the transformed Lagrangian doesn't seem equivalent to the original Lagrangian. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: There's no minus needed for the time derivative so no $\tau_3$, because $\psi^\dagger$ comes with  a time derivative with opposite sign that arises from the integration by parts that takes the time derivative off $\psi$ and onto $\psi^\dagger$..

Comment: $\Psi ^+ (p)\Big( i\partial /\partial t \Big)\Psi (p) = i [\psi ^+        \psi] \Big[ \dot {\psi _1}  
   \dot{\psi _2 ^+} \Big]^T = i\psi_1 ^+\dot{\psi _1} + i\psi _2 \dot{\psi _2 ^+}$ from the (first term of the) transformed Lagrangian. While the first term in the original Lagrangian (eq. (2.1)) is $i\psi _1 ^+ \dot{\psi _1} + i\psi _2 ^+\dot{\psi _2 }$. Both are different. Why?

Comment: Because $\psi_2^\dagger \dot \psi_2 = - \dot \psi_2^\dagger\psi_2 $ up to a total deriative, and $- \dot \psi_2^\dagger\psi_2 = \psi_2 \dot \psi_2^\dagger$ because the fields anticommute. The constants and total derivative do not affect  Lagrange's equations.

Comment: thanks, now I get it.